# What am I missing here when I try to dispatch an action with a fetched json?

Tags: reactjs, forms, redux, react-hooks

I want to update redux state on form submit. But here my action fails or smth else happens so I get the error and component does not render. I dont know if useEffect can help here somehow, but I still didny find out why the error occurs. Should I use redux-form or smth similar?

The error I get: reduxPhotos.map is not a function

ReduxPhotos is a photos array from initialState.

```
const reduxPhotos = useSelector(state => state.photos)
```

So here is a full code:

```
// action

export const addPhotos = (photos) => {
  return {
    type: 'ADD_PHOTOS',
    photos
  }
}

// reducer

const initialState = {
  photos: [],
  collections: [],
  favorites: []
}

function rootReducer (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_PHOTOS':
      return { ...state, photos: action.photos }
    case 'ADD_COLLECTIONS':
      return { ...state, collections: action.collections }
    case 'ADD_TO_FAVORITES':
      return { ...state, favorites: [...state.favorites, action.photo] }
    // case 'REMOVE_FROM_FAVORITES':
    //   return { ...state, collections: action.collections }
    default:
      return state
  }
}

// and here is my Search component

const Search = ({ unsplash }) => {
  

  const reduxPhotos = useSelector(state => state.photos)
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const [value, setValue] = useState('')

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setValue(e.target.value)
  }

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    unsplash.search.photos(value, 1, 10, { orientation: 'portrait', color: 'green' })
      .then(toJson)
      .then(json => {
        console.log(json) // it logs correctly
        dispatch(addPhotos(json)) // this thing does not work
      })
  }

  return (
    <div className='search'>
      ...
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <input className='panel__input' placeholder='Search' onChange={handleChange}/>
          </form>

           <ul className="search__list">
            {reduxPhotos.map((item) => {
              return (
                <li key={item.id} className="search__photo photo">
                  ...
                </li>
              )
            })}
          </ul>
      ...
     </div>
)
```

Comment: Can you please share the error message as well? Also the `addPhotos` code.

Comment: yes, sure, just a minute

Comment: Please take a look again, added details.

Comment: Are you sure `json` what you pass to `addPhotos` is an array? This likely happening because `reduxPhotos` is not an array, it might be an `{}`, `null` or `undefined`. Other thing `reduxPhotos` is maybe `undefined`, you can add `{ reduxPhotos && reduxPhotos.map((item) => {}` check just to be sure.

Comment: Yes its array and all photos from this array are rendered properly until I submit this form. Looks like smth wrong with the form or I use it incorrectly.

Comment: @jakhando In redux devtools you should see the ADD_PHOTOS action, can you display the raw action and copy paste it in your question?

Comment: Added it. Please check it out. Is it what you asked?

Answer (score 0):

**Hello try this:**

```
switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_PHOTOS':
      return [ ...state, {photos: action.photos}]
    default:
      return state
  }
```

or

```
switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_PHOTOS':
      return [ ...state, {action.photos}]
    default:
      return state
  }
```